# Applying additional display settings on new client frames

Tags: frames, emacs-daemon

I have the following function in my emacs config:

```
(defun *make-frame-pretty (frame)
  "`*make-frame-pretty' will apply additional theme settings to make it prettier"
  ;; Add a fringe.
  ;; It's quite nice and makes things easier to read
  (set-fringe-mode
   (/ (- (frame-pixel-width)
         (* 75 (frame-char-width)))
      16))

  (set-default-font "Fira Code"))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions '*make-frames-pretty t)
```

Outside the function, when starting emacs directly, this code applies the font and fringe size, however when starting an emacs daemon and then starting a client frame, it doesn't apply. When setup as a function as a hook like this, it doesn't apply at all.

How can I get this code to run when a new frame is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appearance settings are controlled via [frame parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame-Parameters.html#Frame-Parameters). The simple way to set them is to add the parameters you want to [`default-frame-alist` and `initial-frame-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html#Initial-Parameters). The font is [`font`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html#Font-and-Color-Parameters) and the fringe is [`left-fringe` and `right-fringe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Layout-Parameters.html#Layout-Parameters).

```
(setq my-frame-alist '((font . "Fira Code")
                       (left-fringe . 10)
                       (right-fringe . 10)))
(setq default-frame-alist (append my-frame-alist default-frame-alist))
(setq initial-frame-alist (append my-frame-alist initial-frame-alist))
```

This method doesn't allow you to make the fringe size depend on the frame's initial size. If you want to do that then you have to do it from `after-make-frame-functions`. I think (but I haven't tested) that the problem you're running into is that `after-make-frame-functions` run before the frame is selected, but `set-fringe-mode` and `set-default-font` apply to the selected frame. So to get an automatic fringe size, change `*make-frames-pretty` to select the new frame.

```
(defun *make-frame-pretty (frame)
  "`*make-frame-pretty' will apply additional theme settings to make it prettier"
  (with-selected-frame frame
    ;; Add a fringe.
    ;; It's quite nice and makes things easier to read
    (set-fringe-mode
     (/ (- (frame-pixel-width)
           (* 75 (frame-char-width)))
        16))
   (set-default-font "Fira Code")))
```